# Is it possible to change the axes/part that the vortex forcefield is attracting?

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

INITIAL SITUATION:

So I have a flock of "Birds" that are generated through a Boid Particle System,
at one point in my animation a vertex force field gets activated and the Particles get drawn to it.
My goal is to have it look like the flock of "Birds" is circling around one spot for a specific amount of time.

PROBLEM:

The Vortex Forcefield attracts the Particles at the bottom side of my model, so my "birds" look like they are flying sideways which I don't want.

QUESTION:

Is there a way to change which side of the model is attracted by the Forcefield, or is there a workaround for my problem?

Thanks in advance for your answers and best regards[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is 2 ways to do this.

In the particle settings, go to rotation and uncheck dynamic. This means they all point in one direction.

But I doubt this will give you what you want, its just a quick fix.

The way I find works best is to just take your instance object, enter edit mode, and mess with the rotation and location until you find something that is decent. Rotation works better than location. For it to work, you have to be in edit mode when editing transforms.

Comment: Sadly Boids Particle System doesn't have the rotations setting,
with the other way my "birds" are flying wrong when the forcefield isn't active.

But if nothing else works I will probably have to settle with something in between, that kind of works for both states.

Just wished I could tell the forcefield, which side to attract, don't see the point why it isn't possible -.-

Thanks for your reply though !

Comment: No, the rotation settings isn't ini the boid menu, its in the particle settings.

Comment: You need to click on the object that holds the bird particles, go into the particle, go into rotation, and turn off dynamic

Comment: Well I'm in the particle settings and I know what you mean, but this option is only available if you have not used Boids as the physics type of the particle system, which I most unfortunately did.

Comment: Oh, does the other operation of editing rotation the instance shape work?

Comment: Yes it worked and in the end I settled with that option, as the with the free moving boids the wrong position wasn't that obvious.